# Differential of integral of a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, derivation

Let $Y_{t}$ be

\begin{equation}
Y_{t}=\int_{\Omega} g(X_{u}) du
\end{equation}

where $g(.)$ is a deterministic function and $\Omega=[t_{0},t]$ continuos partition of $\mathbb{R}$. 
Furthermore let $X$ be an Ito process 
\begin{equation}
X_{u}= X_{0}+\int_{0}^{u}\mu(s)ds+\int_{0}^{u} \sigma(s) dW_{s}^{\mathbb{P}} 
\end{equation}
for som well behaved $\mu$ and $\sigma$ and $(W_{s}^{\mathbb{P}})_{0\leq s}$ is standard brownian motion under objective probability measure $\mathbb{P}$.

What is differential of $Y_{t}$?

\begin{equation}
dY_{t}=?
\end{equation}

Comment: Where is the t in the rhs of your equation ?

Comment: @Bob I can relatively easy derive the expression for $g(X_{t})=X_{t}$ namely\begin{equation} dY_{t}=-X_{t}dt+ \int_{\Omega} dX_{u} du\end{equation}. This is done by assuming that the mapping of probability is a continuous function and then using classic calculus (derivative under integral)

Comment: @MJ73550  $t \in \Omega$ in other words $t\in [t_{0}, t_{1}]$ or if your prefer the integral can be written as \begin{equation} \int_{t_{0}}^{t_{1}} g(X(u)) du\end{equation} where $u$ is a dummy.

Comment: @Lost in your certainly mean $\Omega=[t_0,t]$ otherwise there is no point on writing the LHS as $Y(t)$ right? Now is the integrand $g(X_u)$ or $g(u,X_u)$?

Comment: @Quantuple yes it was exactly what I ment. If your confused about $t\in [t_{0}, t_{1}]$ (which is not to contradictory of above statement ) the point was only to explain partition. But to be clear $\Omega=[t_{i},t_{j}]$ , where $t_{i}<t_{j}$. Lastly $g(X_{u})=g(X(u))$.

Comment: @Lost in - Okay and I suppose $X_u$ is an Itô process i.e. $X_u = X_0 + \int_0^u \mu(s) ds + \int_0^u \sigma(s) dW_s$ for some sufficiently well-behaved functions $\mu$ and $\sigma$ and $(W_s)_{s \geq 0}$ a Weiner process?

Comment: in your answer, there is still no dependency on $t$ on your $\int_{t_0}^{t_1}g(X_u)du$, so for the moment $dY_t =0$...

Comment: @quantuple Yes, thanks for pointing that out, I just added that to the question

Comment: @MJ73350 Dependence on $t$ is in $\Omega=[t_{0},t]$ which means that upper bound of integral is $t$.

Comment: @Lost in: Simply put, the case of an integrand $g(X_u)$ is no different from that of an integrand $X_u$ which you managed to write down, since both are Ito processes at the end if the day (assuming that both $g$ and $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are well-behaved). You Can apply the same reasoning. This relationship is sometimes called stochastic Leibniz rule.

Comment: @Quantuple Really ? I have hard time convincing myself about that is the same thing as putting $g(X)$ as well as putting $X$ as integrand. Leibniz rule if I recall correctly is just special case of Ito's formula namely $d(X_t,Y_t)=X_tdY_t+Y_t dX_t + d<X_t,Y_t>$ where $<.>$ is quadratic variation. Do you mean that it's simply breaks down to \begin{equation}dY_{t}=-g(X_{t})dt+ \int_{\Omega} dg(X_{u})du \end{equation} where $dg(X_{u})$ is given by Ito's? in that case I can just change the order of integration and I got  $dY_t$ in terms of integrals in drift and diffusion parts.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/230996/analogue-of-leibniz-rule-for-stochastic-integrals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\Bbb{P})$ equipped with the (augmentation of the) natural filtration ${\bf{F}}=(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ of a $\mathbb{P}$-Wiener process $(W_t)_{t\geq 0}$, consider the Itô process 
$$ X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t \mu(s) ds + \int_0^t \sigma(s) dW_s \tag{1} $$

for some sufficiently well-behaved functions $\mu$ and $\sigma$, such that the stochastic integration can be defined in the Itô sense.

Define the integral
$$Y_t = \int_0^t X_u du $$

From $(1)$ it follows that 
\begin{align}
Y_t &= \int_0^t \left( X_0 + \int_0^u \mu(s) ds + \int_0^u \sigma(s) dW_s \right) du \\
&= X_0 t + \int_0^t \int_0^u \mu(s) ds du + \int_0^t \int_0^u \sigma(s) dW_s du 
\end{align}
Using (stochastic) Fubini theorem one can permute the integration order and write
\begin{align}
Y_t &= X_0 t + \int_0^t \int_s^t \mu(s) du  ds + \int_0^t \int_s^t \sigma(s) du dW_s \\
&= X_0 t + \int_0^t (t-s) \mu(s) ds + \int_0^t (t-s) \sigma(s) dW_s \\
&= \left(X_0 + \int_0^t \mu(s) ds + \int_0^t \sigma(s) dW_s\right) t - \int_0^t s \mu(s) ds - \int_0^t s \sigma(s) dW_s \\
&= X_t t - \underbrace{\int_0^t s \mu(s) ds}_{\text{classic integral}} - \underbrace{\int_0^t s \sigma(s) dW_s}_{\text{Itô integral}} \\
\end{align} 
And one can now appeal to the usual "differential" definition (whether from standard calculus or Itô calculus) to write:
\begin{align}
dY_t &= \underbrace{X_t dt + t dX_t + 0}_{d(X_t t)\,\,\,\text{Itô's lemma}} - t \mu(t) dt -t \sigma(t) dW_t \\
&= X_t dt + t dX_t - t \underbrace{(\mu(t) dt + \sigma(t) dW_t)}_{dX_t} \\
&= X_t dt
\end{align}
Now as mentioned in the comments, because any smooth function $g(X_t)$ will also be an Itô process, you can repeat the reasoning with $\tilde{X}_t := g(X_t)$ to get, for your particular problem,
$$ dY_t = \tilde{X}_t dt = g(X_t) dt $$

**[Remark]** Should $X_u = X(u) \to X(t,u)$ with an additional, explicit dependence on $t$ things can get more complicated. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/230996/analogue-of-leibniz-rule-for-stochastic-integrals) related question on math SE.

**[Edit]** Just saw that this was discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298990/stochastic-differential-equation-for-time-integral-of-stochastic-process) as well.